# Finding intensity of laser after round trip in cavity with single mirror

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, laser, geometric-optics, laser-cavity

I came across a question in a text book today, and was wondering if someone could maybe check to see if my physics and workings are correct, as I am getting a intensity value greater the what going into the cavity which dose not make sense to me, as when I look at one of my optics book it say that if there mirror was there that had been taken away I should get back the original intensity which I don't, but I don't understand what wrong with my method.

So the question is as follows.

> A helium neon laser operating at $632\pm0.05$nm consists of a discharge tube of length $0.3$m with mirrors bonded to the ends. The output mirror is flat, while the other mirror is spherical with radius of curvature of 3m. The reflection coefficient of the two mirrors are both equal $0.99$ while the gain medium is characterised by line-width of $1500$MHz and an index of refraction $n=1$
>
> g) Let us remove the spherical mirror. Given that the distributed cavity loss (over the whole cavity) coefficient is $5\times 10^{-3}/cm$ and the signal gain coefficient of the active medium is $5 \times 10^{-2}/cm$, evaluate the intensity of the laser beam after a round trip through the cavity. Starting intensity is $1pW$

My workings

Diagram of the situation
[image]

Ignore cavity length it suppose to be $30cm$. So as the light beam passes through the medium, it will experience gain losses in the medium due to some undesired transition and absorptions, so we can from the follwing equation.

$I_1=I_0e^{(G-L)x}$

where

G=gain in the medium

L=Losses in the medium

Now as we have a highly reflective mirror assume losses are small so then $I_2$ becomes.

$I_2=I_0*Re^{(G-L)x}$

Using the same logic as it passes back through the medium $I_3$ is given by

$I_3=I_0*Re^{2(G-L)x}$

The subbing in the numbers

$G=5 \times 10^{-2}/cm $

$L=5 \times 10^{-3}/cm$

$R=0.99$

$x=30cm$

$I_0=10^{-12}$

Then I make the final intensity is $I=1.7 \times 10^{-12}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One hidden assumption is that the initial beam is collimated; otherwise there will be geometric changes in intensity.  That said, the gain is greater than the loss so you would expect $I_3$ to be greater than $I_0$. This makes sense, because otherwise the laser could not operate at all even with two mirrors.